# Retrieve the previous date for each record SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I would like to retrieve the previous customer contract effective date for each record. How do I write a query such that it will give me the following result? This is for sql server. Do I use over `partition by`? Thanks!

```
Customer Eff_Date   Previous_Eff  
     A    1/1/2013    NULL   
     A    2/1/2014    1/1/2013   
     A    3/1/2015    2/1/2014    
     B    2/1/2014    NULL   
     B    3/1/2014    2/1/2014
```

Comment: Which version of of SQL Server do you use?

Comment: Do you want B's previous EFF date for 3/1/2014 to be A's Eff Date at 2/1/2014 ?

Answer (score 3):

```
select customer, eff_date,
lag(eff_date) over(partition by customer order by eff_date) as previous_eff
from tablename;
```

You can use the `lag` function to get the value of the previous row's effdate.

This is a different way to do it using `row_number` function if you are using a SQL Server version older than 2012.

```
with x as 
(select customer, eff_date,
row_number() over(partition by customer order by eff_date) as rn
from tablename)
select x.customer, x.eff_date, x1.eff_date as previous_eff
from x left join x x1 on x.customer = x1.customer
and x.rn = x1.rn + 1
```

SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/faf40/9

Comment: `LAG` is available starting from SQL Server 2012.

Comment: @HamletHakobyan..included another way of doing it using `row_number`

Comment: You have 2 inaccuracy in query.

Comment: @HamletHakobyan THanks! I just found out I have the 2008 version so I cannot use lag function...

Comment: @vkp I am a little confused by the x1.eff_date, shouldn't it be x.rn?

Comment: @vkp and what is x1 table?

Comment: @Futochan..it was an alias for the `cte` x. i missed it.thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: you join on the previous row and select the date from that row.

Comment: Still 1 inaccuracy in query.

Comment: can you point that out please @HamletHakobyan? i am thinking if it should be a `left join`?

Comment: Yes, it have to be `LEFT JOIN` and you should correct join condition. `x.rn = x1.rn + 1`

Comment: @Futochan..sql fiddle link has been provided.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to select the previous date using a subquery that will work on most dbs

```
select *, 
    (select max(Eff_Date) from mytable b
    where b.Customer = a.Customer
    and b.Eff_Date < a.Eff_Date) Previous_Eff
from mytable a
```